# Nhibernate table per hierachy and self reference table

Tags: nhibernate

I have such a problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Altkom.Model" namespace="Altkom.Model">
  <class name ="Employee" table="Employee" discriminator-value="Employee">
    <id name ="EmployeeId" column="EmployeeId">
      <generator class="uuid.hex" />
    </id>
    <discriminator column="Discriminator" not-null="true" type="System.String"/>
    <property name="FirstName" column="FirstName" not-null="true" />
    <property name="LastName" column="LastName" not-null="true" />
    <property name="BirthDate" column="BirthDate" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="Sex" column="Sex" not-null="true" />
    <!--<property name="ManagerId" column="ManagerId"/>-->
    <component name="Address" class="Altkom.Model.Address, Altkom.Model">
      <property name="City" column="City" not-null="true" />
      <property name="Street" column="Street" not-null="true" />
      <property name="Country" column="Country" not-null="true" />
      <property name="ZipCode" column="ZipCode" not-null="true" />
    </component>
    <bag name="Projects" table="EmployeeProject" lazy="true">
      <key column="EmployeeId"/>
      <many-to-many column="ProjectId" class="Project" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="JobHistories" lazy="false">
      <key column="EmployeeId"/>
      <one-to-many class="JobHistory"/>
    </bag>
    <many-to-one name ="Manager" class="Altkom.Model.Manager, Altkom.Model" column="ManagerId"/>
    <subclass name="Manager" discriminator-value="Manager">
      <!--<many-to-one name ="Employee" class="Altkom.Model.Employee, Altkom.Model" column="EmployeeId" not-null="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false"/>-->
      <bag name="Subordinates" lazy="false" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="ManagerId"/>
        <one-to-many class="Employee"/>
      </bag>
      <property name="RoomNumber" column="RoomNumber"/>
    </subclass>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [EmployeeId] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Discriminator] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [BirthDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Sex] [int] NOT NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Street] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ZipCode] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ManagerId] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [RoomNumber] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK74988DB23FED7E5D] FOREIGN KEY([ManagerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK74988DB23FED7E5D]
GO
```

What should I do to make Subordinates property works good.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It is certainly possible to create a collection of objects that come from a self referencing data set using NHibernate.  But right now we don't even know what if any problems you are having.   It would take more effort than most people have to spend on theses questions to actually get your code to attempt to run.  There is little point in even bothering to look at someone else's mapping file without even knowing what the problem is.  You need to describe any errors you are getting or behavior that does not meet your needs and someone can probably answer.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. My problem is with Subordinates collection. This property is always empty, even if I have records on the database which match to the criteria. There is no error which I get. Everything looks good but only these one property doesn't behave like I want to.

Comment: Hi again,Everything works good. My mistake I have to go sleep :-)

Comment: OK. I think you may find this model overly restrictive and problematic in the future.  Modelling "roles" by inheritance leads to problems.  In your model, if someone is a "Manager" that is a *fundamental* part of their entity identity.  If we have a base class "Mammal", we could have subclasses "Cat"," Dog", "Human" and those would all be part of a true fundamental entity identity.  "Manager" does not fit that paradigm, it is a role, transient, not identity.  I advise a single class (Person or Employee, etc) with collection of Role objects.  A Role would be "Manager" etc.

Answer (score 0):

We use a fairly similar structure in an NH application. The differences I can see with your mapping are:

1) We do not nest the class definitions
2) We specify fetch='select' on the many-to-one element
3) We use lazy='true' on the bag element

So reworking your mapping would look like:

```
<class name ="Employee" table="Employee" discriminator-value="Employee">
   ...
   <many-to-one name ="Manager" fetch="select" class="Altkom.Model.Manager, Altkom.Model" column="ManagerId"/>
   ...
</class>
<subclass name="Manager" extends="Employee" discriminator-value="Manager">
   <bag name="Subordinates" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
     <key column="ManagerId"/>
     <one-to-many class="Employee"/>
   </bag>
   ...
</subclass>
```

[As an aside I question whether you really want to use a subclass for Manager. What happens when someone gets promoted? Or you simply want to assign a junior subordinate? You will need to change the type of this object and probably recreate the row and update all associated records I generally only use a different class where there is fairly strong type immutability]